# TypeError:ndarray not callable in scipy.stats.kstest()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to perform a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to compare an empirical distribution with the F distribution (I know these can't be compared directly, but I will employ bootstrapping). I'm having a problem with the scipy KS test:

```
readLengths = [list,of,int,values,...]
x = stats.f.fit(readLengths)
dfn=x[0]
dfd=x[1]
stats.kstest(readLengths,stats.f.rvs(dfn,dfd,size=100))
```

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

and it points to the stats.kstest line. I assume this is a problem with the readLengths array, but the docs say it can take a 1D array, so not sure why I'm having this problem. Also, interestingly in this function you can name the normal distribution with 'norm', but 'f' doesn't appear to be valid, despite that being the scipy name for the F distribution.

Comment: Try to change readLenghts to `list(readLenghts)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html):

> **cdf** : str or callable
>
> If a string, it should be the name of a distribution in scipy.stats. If rvs is a string then cdf can be False or the same as rvs. If a callable, that callable is used to calculate the cdf.

The second argument to `kstest` should either be a **string** or a **callable object** that accepts quantiles as inputs and returns the CDF. Instead you are passing it

```
stats.f.rvs(dfn,dfd,size=100)
```

which evaluates to an `np.ndarray`.

---

One option would be to construct a frozen PDF using your desired parameters, then pass its `.cdf` method as the second argument to `kstest`:

```
fdist = stats.f(dfn, dfd)
d, p = stats.kstest(readLengths, fdist.cdf)
```

Comment: I guess newer version of scipy does accept array-like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html